# Getting raw SQL query built from ActiveRecord in CodeIgniter 1.7

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to debug some code in my first serious CodeIgniter app and I can't seem to find where I can simply get the raw SQL that my ActiveRecord code just generated.

```
$where  = 'DAY(`datetime_start`) = '. date('d',$day) .' AND ';
$where .= 'MONTH(`datetime_start`) = '. date('m',$day) .'';

$this->db->from('events')->where($where);
$result = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Before the query runs:

```
$this->db->_compile_select();
```

And after it has run:

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

Comment: _compile_select() is marked as protected in more recent versions of CodeIgniter (it likely only wasn't declared protected before for PHP4 compatibility). So you could just set the limit to 1 to avoid executing a big query and then call last_query(), or you could use reflection but the first option is preferable.

Comment: Also: It looks like get_compiled_select() will be available in a future version of CodeIgniter; it's already in the dev branch (https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_query_builder.php). I copied that method to DB_active_rec and it worked fine, even in conjunction with this library: https://github.com/NTICompass/CodeIgniter-Subqueries

Answer (score 10):

Of course, I found it 2 minutes after posting, courtesy of [Phil Sturgeon](http://www.philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2009/05/Debugging-ActiveRecord-queries-in-CodeIgniter).

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Answer (score 8):

Also, you can put the following in your controller:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

You'll get queries and a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this old post and wondering what this is in the latest v3 the function is $this->db->get_compiled_select().

Answer (score -2):

You can make something like this until CI's next version is released

```
private function get_query_string()
{
    return  'SELECT ' . 
            implode( ' , ' , $this->db->ar_select ) .
            ' FROM ' .
            implode( ' , '  , $this->db->ar_from ) .
            ( count( $this->db->ar_where ) ? ' WHERE ' : '' ) .
            implode( ' ' , $this->db->ar_where );
}
```

Comment: This is very unlikely to yield accurate results as to what query is actually being run