# Sql WHERE query with codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have for example this query:

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE (column_1 = 1 OR column_1 = 2) AND (column_2 = 12 OR column_2 = 3)
```

How can I write it on Codeigniter?

I think something like:

```
$where = column_1 = 1 OR column_1 = 2;
$this->db->where($where);
$where2 = column_2 = 12 OR column_2 = 3;
$this->db->where($where2);
```

(I need to separate between each AND)

Is this ok? I don't have an idea how I can see the query as string only.

Comment: And what is wrong with your code except missing **"**? Doesn't it work?

Comment: Between the WHERE statement there is 'AND'? that I don't know. How can I see the query as string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507710/getting-raw-sql-queries-in-codeigniter here you'll find an answer to "How can I see the query as string?"

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you need something like this:

```
$this->db->where("(column_1 = 1 OR column_1 = 2) AND (column_2 = 12 OR column_2 = 3)");
```

Or what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Use `where_in`.

```
$this->db->where_in('column_1', array(1, 2));
$this->db->where_in('column_2', array(2, 13));
```

It will be easier to read.